# how to use strlen and check for minimum and maximum word count

Tags: php

I am trying to use the code below and not sure if the second syntax will work as well. Is there also a way to check to see if an user has typed consecutive letters such as "aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbb" etc?

```
 if(strlen($joined)<200 || strlen($joined) > 500) {

              header("Location: index.php?reply_registration_form=invalidlength");
        exit();
```

Can I also do this?

```
  if(strlen($joined)<200 || $joined > 500) {

              header("Location: index.php?reply_registration_form=invalidlength");
        exit();
```

Comment: The second syntax tests if the value of `$joined` is a number than's more than 500, it doesn't do anything with the length.

Comment: Neither of these counts the number of words, they're counting the number of characters in `$joined`.

Comment: You can use a regular expression to test for repeated letters. `(.)\1{4}` will match if there are at least 5 consecutive repetitions.

Comment: So would I do something like if((.)\1{4}) {};?

Comment: How would you make it to test for at least two consecutive letters? would i change the number 4 to 1?

Comment: Yes, there are many SO questions about using regexp to match repeated letters.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that? Lots of ordinary words have 2 consecutive letters.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `preg_replace`

```
<?
   php echo preg_replace("/(.)\\1+/", "$1", "aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbb"); // shows 'ab'
?>
```

Comment: I guess if I wanted to test for 4 consecutive letters, would I change the 1+ to 4+?

Comment: If you want to test it you should write your own code. As I understand you want to check "If the string has max 4 consecutive letters return true, otherwise return false". Am I true?